# How to change the OData EDM Model on the runtime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, odata, microservices

In an OData service a dynamic EDM model had been registered and created

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapODataServiceRoute("OData", "odata", GetEdmModel());
}
```

GetEdmModel()

```
private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(); 
    modelBuilder.AddEntitySet("Movies", modelBuilder.AddEntityType(externalEntity));
    return modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

Accessing the Metadata URL give me the right model 
http://odatasample/OData/$metadata  everything is running fine,

But the problem is `externalEntity` is not constant and can change in the runtime.

Is there is anyway to change the OData EDM Model in the runtime?

Comment: Do you really want to "automatically" change a database at runtime?  What happens if a hacker attacks your database?

Comment: You can follow the code in here: https://github.com/cuongle/DynamicOdata

Comment: I'm aware of that repo, and it doesn't support run-time changes, so let's say you added new table on the db, you have to restart the service instance in IIS, because it's using a resolver that is scanning the tables in the startup, but it doesn't keep an eye on the DB and update the model according

Comment: While you could do something like a generic repository, I'm not sure how you expect to have an entity to map it to if a new table were created.

Comment: long story short, no worries we have types ATM. We have a different ways to get the type, but all of them were involving reflection and caching. We are trying to avoid that, but OData and EF were forcing us to have a Type. it's good to have a short TTM but not good for the long run, as we start focusing on Performance and scalability.

Comment: Did you found any way to deal with this?